# Binary WebSockets in Flash

Tags: flash, websocket

Is it possible to send binary (blob) data down a WebSocket equivalent in Flash?

I've heard that you can hijack an XMLSocket for text-based messaging. Is it possible to do this for binary types?

Any resources much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, have a look at the [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Sunil in his comment, instead of using an `XMLSocket` you can use a `Socket`:

From http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html:

> The Socket class enables code to establish Transport Control Protocol
>   (TCP) socket connections for sending and receiving binary data.
>
> The Socket class is useful for working with servers that use binary
>   protocols.
>
> To use the methods of the Socket class, first use the constructor,
>   `new Socket`, to create a Socket object.

It looks like someone has taken advantage of this to create a complete WebSocket equivalent in AS3: https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket (which supports both text and binary data, I believe).